# Add Members to Distribution Groups DLs

Tags: powershell, active-directory, office365, exchange-server

I have below .csv input file. These are the Distribution Groups.
Level-4 is member of Level3,
Level-3 is member of Level2,
Level-2 is member of Level1,
Level-1 is member of Level0.

[image]

So far, I have tried the below code. Starting to add Level-4 into Level-3. I have marked them for better understanding. However, I am not able to select the object and iterate in correct way using PowerShell.

e.g. First instance of Level-3 DL is 'DL_L3_US1' and it will contain members from Level-4 i.e. DL_L4_US1 and DL_L4_US2. How do I make this work?

`$DLlist = Import-Csv C:\tempfile\Book2.csv`

`$Test = $DLlist | select Level3,Level4 | ? {$_.level3 -notlike $null }`

`foreach ($x in $DLlist)`

`{Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity "$($x.Level3)" -Member "$($x.Level4)"}`

Comment: I posted another answer. Sorry for initially misunderstanding the question.

Comment: @Jeetcu, how did you get that file in the screenshot or the Book2.csv? Can you share the script here as well ? ;-)

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer. It was manually prepared and maintain by someone in team. Don't have any script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So my first answer wasn't correct.  I misunderstood the question.  Here's a new example:

```
$Props     = 'Level-0','Level-1','Level-2','Level-3','Level-4'
$GroupDefs = Import-Csv C:\temp\Book2.csv

For( $i = 0; $i -lt $GroupDefs.Count; ++$i )
{   # Loop through the objects that came from the CSV file...
    For( $p = 1; $p -lt $Props.Count; ++$p )
    {   # Loop through the known properties...
        $Prop      = $Props[$p]   # Convenience var
        $GroupProp = $Props[$p-1] # Convenience var

        If( $GroupDefs[$i].$Prop ) {
            # If the property is populated then loop backwards from $i-1, 
            # the group def record just prior to the current one.
            
            $Member = $GroupDefs[$i].$Prop
            :Inner For($r = ($i-1); $r -ge 0; --$r)
            {
                If( $GroupDefs[$r].$GroupProp ) {
                    # This means you hit the first record behind your current
                    # position that has the previous property populated.  Now 
                    # we know the group...
                    
                    $Group = $GroupDefs[$r].$GroupProp
                    Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $Group -Member $Member -WhatIf
                    Break Inner
                }            
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By using traditional For Loops we can find values at other positions. So, the way I worked this out is to nest a loop of the known properties in a loop of the group definitions. When I find a property that has a value, I then loop backward from the current position in `$GroupDefs` until I find the previous property populated.  By that point, I've managed to find both the group and the member, so I can run the command.

**Update for Comments:**

There is no Dot sourcing in this program.  Dot referencing is used.  As previously mentioned `.` is an operator in the sense that the right-hand side will be evaluated before the property is referenced, hence we can use a variable or expression.

Imagine that you are going through the spreadsheet line by line.  That is the outer loop of `$GroupDefs`.  You can look at the value of `$i` as if it's a row#.

Now, for each of those rows, I want to look at each of a known set of property names.  So we're going to loop through `$Props`.  If one of those properties has a value, I then want to look at previous rows to find the nearest previous row where the previous property (`$Prop[$p-1]`) is populated.  For example, if Level-2 is populated in Row# 3 I know I have to look back through rows 2, 1, 0 to find the first previous value for property Level-1.  That part is the innermost loop, which moves backward through the `$GroupDefs` array from the current position -1 (`$p = ($i-1)`) to 0.  When the first populated previous value for Level-1 is found I know that's the group name.

`$Member` is a convenience variable.  It's set to `$GroupDefs[$i].$Prop` because the value of the given property is the member we wish to add to the yet to be determined group.

Note: `$GroupDefs.$i` returning nothing is expected.  At any given moment `$i` is a number determined by the loop, but it is not the name of a property on the `$GroupDefs` array or any objects within it.  So, it will neither return any property value from the array itself nor will it unroll (enumerate) any properties from the objects contained within.

Note: The value of `$Prop` will change as you loop through the properties and until a value is found on a property by the given name.

I realize this is confusing, but if you step through the code you will better understand what's happening.  First, try to understand what's literally being done.  Then the code should make more sense...

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. But, I am still struggling with the logic here and in more complex way.
PS C:\> `($GroupDefs).Count` - So far this var is good.
`313`
PS C:\> `$i` - This var incrementing the value as expected
`30`
PS C:\> `$GroupDefs.$i` - When executed its blank
PS C:\> `$Prop` - This var has value
`Level-1`
PS C:\> `$GroupDefs[$i].$prop` - When executed its blank
PS C:\>
Weird thing is after sometime i execute the same var's it shows values in it and when i ran $GroupDefs[$i].$prop again its disappears.

Comment: Not sure if "." source is working at my end. I am trying "IF" statement with ($GroupDefs[$i]  -and $prop). This evaluates to true. Also, what values will be stored in here?
`$Member = $GroupDefs[$i].$Prop`

Comment: @Stevn. As you said code make more sense to me. Let me test this and come back. Thanks.

Comment: Excellent!!! it worked :). I was doing a silly mistake. Headers in .csv file corrected and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: @Steven can you pls help here as well. I really need this. Thanks in advance. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73343138/logic-for-dl-migration-batch-preparation-powershell