# Logic for DL Migration Batch Preparation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, powershell, excel-formula

**I have 140K DLs (Distribution Groups) to be migrated and requirement is to prepare the Batch from .csv input file which contains 140K DLs.

Below is the sample data of .csv file.

| DL Name | Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | Set |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DL1 | --- | --- | DL2 | --- | Set-1 |
| DL2 | --- | --- | --- | DL1 | Set-1 |
| DL3 | --- | --- | --- | --- | Set-2 |
| DL9 | --- | --- | --- | --- | Set-3 |
| DL7 | --- | DL3 | --- | --- | Set-2 |
| DL10 | --- | DL4^DL5^DL6 | --- | --- | Set-4 |
| DL8 | --- | --- | --- | --- | Set-5 |
| DL6 | --- | --- | --- | DL10^DL5 | Set-4 |
| DL5 | --- | --- | --- | --- | Set-4 |
| DL4 | --- | DL5^DL6 | --- | --- | Set-4 |

So, the requirement is to prepare set in such a way that it can be easily tracked.
e.g. If DL1 (row 1) is marked as Set-1 and any of the column contains other DL, in this case its DL2 (in Column3) then it is marked as Set-1. Similarly, Now if we iterate to each row the Set is prepared and numbered in last column.

one more example, DL10 contains DL4,DL5,DL6 and marked as Set-4, accordingly the DL4,DL5,DL6 will be marked also as Set-4 cause they are in DL10's Column2. Further, DL6,DL5,DL4 are also related in some way and marked as Set-4.

So far I have tried below code but it only helps when we are running the live commands and also it keeps looping if duplicates are found. It has many limitations and doesn't fits the requirement. e.g. DL1 contains DL2 and DL2 contains DL1. Kind of nested to each other. So I am looking for a solution to manipulate and work with .csv file dump that I have already shared above as a sample data.

```
$Groups = New-Object -TypeName "System.Collections.ArrayList"
$Groups = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
$dump = $Groups.Add("$($GroupName)")
$final = New-Object -TypeName "System.Collections.ArrayList"
$final = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
for($i=0; $i -lt $Groups.count; $i++){
$group = $Groups[$i]
$members = Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $Group
foreach($member in $members){
if($member.RecipientType -like "*Group"){
$dump = $Groups.Add("$($member.Name)")
}
else{
$dump = $final.Add("$($member.Name)")
}
}
}
$final = $final | Sort -Unique
$final | Out-File -FilePath ".\MemberList_$($GroupName).txt"
$path = pwd
Write-Host "The member list can be found at $($path)\MemberList_$($GroupName).txt" -ForegroundColor Green
```

I really appreciate the response to help solve this complex puzzle. :)

**Note: Looking to develop a code not only in PowerShell but Python or Excel formula **

Comment: I will not be able to code this until later today.

Comment: @Steven. No problem take your time. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @Steven . Any hopes.?  :)

Comment: I have been working on it. I think I have a working idea, but I need to formalize and test it.  Maybe this afternoon.

Comment: @Steven. Thanks for an update. I am still scratching my head around it. :(

Comment: @Steven any luck or update please? :)

Comment: There's too much ambiguity going on here. What is the expected result?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala . I have already mentioned the requirement with examples and what is expected results. Please let me know if any clarification needed.

Comment: @Jeetcu, I would like clarification. Perhaps a rephrase?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala. In other words requirement is to fill the last column with batch/set numbers. How? e.g. If DL1 (row 1) is marked as Set-1 and any of the other columns contains other DL, in this case its DL2 (in Column3) then it is marked as Set-1. Similarly, Now if we iterate to each row the Set is prepared and numbered in last column.

Comment: @Jeetcu what happens if DL1 is marked as Set-1, and it has DL2 in column3, but DL2 is marked as Set-10 for example?

Comment: @Vivere - once you start marking you have to validate if it's already been marked and if yes, assign that value. If not, then assign new set. Hope I am able to explain here :)

Comment: @Steven Any thoughts please.?

Comment: @Vivere - Any progress please

Comment: Sorry I have been super swamped and haven't even been checking in on SO much.  Challenge is always to find a solid block of time to commit.  I'll be on a trip next 2 days which should give me some alone time for this.  I throw it on my calendar to make sure I don't forget.  Sorry for the delays...

Comment: @Steven no problem. :) Thanks for the response and hope you have wonderful trip ahead.

Comment: @Steven have had a chance to look into it? I am still struggling to crack this. :)

Comment: Yet no luck for this

Comment: Yet the same ...

Comment: All, Any comments?